# Signed exe becomes unsigned after adding project output in setup package using visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project, signing

I have created a msi setup package using visual studio 2008. I have added a project's output (exe project), which is signed at post build, to the setup package. The project is signed at the output directory (bin\Release). but when install the setup package, the exe found unsigned at the installed location. Why is the signing becomes invalid ?

When i add it as a file it is signed. But when i add it as Project Output to the setup project it becomes unsigned. (I'm doing signing process at post build)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's something like the Primary Output files being used from the obj folder, not the output folder.  I think you can look at the Properties of Primary Output to see.

Comment: ya you are right, thanks buddy, I tried signing the exe in bin\release before. Now i sign the exe in obj\release which is the project output.